# Analog of SetThreadExecutionState in kernel32.dll for UWP

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp

Many if not all "classic" WinAPI functions (including `SetThreadExecutionState` in `kernel32.dll`) are not officially supported in UWP. Despite the fact that they can actually work in these applications.

The question is whether there are equivalent? Of course interested in primarily `SetThreadExecutionState`.

Comment: Probably might be useful to know your intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want a device to stay active while your UWP app is running.

A simple way to achieve that is using

```
displayRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
displayRequest.RequestActive();

// Do not forget to release afterwards
displayRequest.RequestRelease();
```